# Can revealing module pattern be done without IIFE like this and serve same purpose?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, encapsulation, iife

My understanding of revealing module pattern is as follows:

**CODE #1**

```
const iifeModulePattern = (function () {
  const secretSeed = 999; // ← private
  const logSecretCode = function(){console.log(secretSeed+1)};
  return {methodForPublic : logSecretCode};
})();

iifeModulePattern.methodForPublic();
```

So far I hope I'm not wrong. My question is:

1. Won't the following Code #2 serve same purpose?
2. If it does, why is Code #1 popular than Code #2?
3. If it doesn't, what's the difference?

**CODE #2**

```
const modulePattern = () => {
  const secretSeed = 999; // ← private
  const logSecretCode = function(){console.log(secretSeed+1)};
  return {methodForPublic : logSecretCode};
};

modulePattern().methodForPublic();
```

*I won't store "secret" codes (like passwords) in this way. The above codes are just examples.*

Comment: Approach 2 is more verbose, and blurs the intent of the code if you're only going to call it once. IMO, in professional code, IIFEs are somewhat obsolete now that we have modules - no need to constrain scope if declaring stuff on the top level doesn't leak globally

Comment: The IIFE/function is pointless if you don't declare your "local" variables and they end up in global space.

Comment: @Thomas What a stupid mistake... I reviewed my code many times but I forgot! I'll edit my question right away

Answer (score 1):

```js
const iifeModulePattern = (function() {
  let value = 0; // private
  return {
    next: () => (value = 134775813 * value + 1) >>> 0
  };
})();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  console.log("iifeModulePattern.next()", i, iifeModulePattern.next());
}

console.log("The basic IIFE.");
console.log("");

const modulePattern = () => {
  let value = 0; // private
  return {
    next: () => (value = 134775813 * value + 1) >>> 0
  };
};

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  console.log("modulePattern().next()", i, modulePattern().next());
}
console.log("Kinda pointless this way, ain't it? Everytime, the sequence starts all over.");
console.log("");

const instance1 = modulePattern();
const instance2 = modulePattern();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log("instance1.next()", i, instance1.next());
  if (i & 1) {
    console.log("instance2.next()", i, instance2.next());
  }
}
console.log("This usage makes more sense.\nAnd the two instances progress independant of each other.");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

> Won't the following Code #2 serve same purpose?

Yes, No, maybe; it depends on how you use it.

> If it doesn't, what's the difference?

`iifeModulePattern` is a singleton, `modulePattern()` is a factory.

> If it does, why is Code #1 popular than Code #2?

What's the purpose of giving the factory a name, store it in a variable if all you'll ever do is to call it once, right here, right now?